# How to get the data for the edge between two nodes?

Tags: python, networkx

I want to get the edge between two nodes in a networkx graph. More specifically, I want to get some data associated with this edge. I know *a priori* that these two nodes are linked. Is there a function to do this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Draw an edge between two specific nodes that you know are connected, or search for nodes which have an edge and then compute something based on other attributes those nodes have?

Comment: @Reti43 I mean, given two nodes, `u` and `v`, get the edge that connects them.

Comment: Something like [`get_edge_data()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.get_edge_data.html)? There's also [`edges()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.edges.html), but that returns a list of the nodes that are connected.

Answer (score 20):

The edge data are stored in a dictionary.  To access that dictionary, use `get_edge_data()`.

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2, weight=5)
G.get_edge_data(1,2)
> {'weight': 5}
```

If you want to iterate through all the edges you can use `G.edges(data=True)`

```
H = nx.Graph()
H.add_edge(2, 3, color = 'red')
H.add_edge(1, 2, weight = 4)
for u,v,data in H.edges(data=True):
    print(u, v, data)
> 1 2 {'weight': 4}
> 2 3 {'color': 'red'}
```

Comment: So I tried this with a graph that has multiple edges between two nodes, A and B. One edge has a weight of 40, second edge has a value of 50, and the third edge has a value of 60. Using nx.get_edge_data will only return the last edge (with value of 60). Is there a command that will return all the weights?

Comment: When I do `G.get_edge_data(1,2)` for a `MultiGraph` with 2 edges between 1 and 2, it gives me both edges and their weights.  If you are having a different experience, you should probably post a new question.  [are you sure the graph has multiple edges? - if it's not a `MultiGraph` or `MultiDiGraph`, then each time you've added an edge you've overwritten the previous edge]

Comment: Thanks, I finally discovered Mulitgraph hours after posting my question.

Comment: For anyone wondering, if you use nx.Graph() and add an edge from 1 to 2. You can also say nx.get_edge_data(2,1). This will receive the same edge

Comment: @Gertjan Brouwer I believe you mean G.get_edge_data(2,1).